How to Remove White Space from Windows User Root Path
I use a Microsoft Surface Pro 7 laptop running Windows 11 Pro, and on purchase, the default user profile was "Surface Pro 7", for which the user profile path was C:\Users\Surface Pro 7.
I want to edit that root path and remove the Whitespaces from it. Why? I figured some of the packages I have installed tend to run some executables from within the user profile, and it always fails with the error:
'C:\Users\Surface' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program of batch file.

which makes sense because of the whitespace within the path URL.
Is there some way I can edit that path? Or use some sort of alias to direct programs trying to access %USERPROFILE% to get a path without the whitespace?
I experienced this last when I tried to work with the Algorand algokit package at the point when I executed algokit init for my project.
Attempts Made

I have previously tried changing the username of the default profile via Computer Management. However, this did not change the default profile Home path.

I have also attempted creating a new user profile and copying files across the Surface Pro 7 and the new one leaving behind the NTUSER.DAT file.
However, it didn't work out, but the PC only created a temp profile instead when I tried logging into the newly created profile. Of course, changes in C:\Users\TEMP are not persisted after signing out, so it was not useful.

I also tried making some edits to some of the keys in Registry as was suggested in some other Windows forum but it did not work out as well.


I really do not want to create a new profile. I would generally prefer if I could change this default profile name, and propagate the change to the %USERPROFILE% path.
